# My understanding of the term 'complexity'

Tags: terminology, computer-science, computational-complexity

I have organized the term 'complexity' in mathematics.
Am I understanding correctly ?

1. In common English 'complexity' means the degree of complicated-ness.
2. But in mathematics, 'complexity' means something different. It can mean either 'time complexity' or 'space complexity'.
3. When the term 'complexity' alone is used, it means 'time complexity'.
4. The term 'time complexity' refers to the speed of an algorithm; how fast one can solve a problem using the algorithm.
5. The term 'space complexity' refers to the amount of memory needed for solving the algorithm. "How many sheets of paper do I need to solve the problem."
6. For evaluating space complexity, one can erase some texts on sheets when the texts are no longer needed. In this way you can save total needed sheets of paper.
7. If there is no other specification, an integer input/output is usually considered "given as binary". If no other specification, Time complexity and Space complexity are evaluated, assuming given integer input/output is of a binary form.
8. In fact the fact 7) is not that important, because almost all interesting algorithms need  fairly big time complexity (take long time) compared to complexity of converting base of an integer (ex: binary to decimal or vice-versa). It is like for 100 seconds(main algorithm)+0.01 seconds(converting base), 0.01 seconds is negligible. I think it is similar for space complexity.

You can give opinions for each description 1.–8.

Comment: I think there might be other meanings for “complexity” in other areas of math, but these to are the basic meanings of computational complexity.

Comment: A point to add though: usually if the time used is doubled, the complexity is considered the same. We mostly care about asymptotic complexity.

Comment: To sort of piggy back on @ThomasAndrews comment, in my own echo chamber, when I hear the word "complexity," I think of descriptive complexity. Strictly speaking, descriptive complexity escapes computational complexity since it is dealing with subsets of complete metrizable separable spaces. I just stumbled across these slides which seem like a promising sketch: http://calvino.polito.it/~camerlo/genoa2017.pdf

Comment: If you take the analogy of human mind as a computer with finite memory, for your statement 1 in common English, can you elaborate what do you mean "degree of complicated-ness", what's really complicated-ness in English for you?

Comment: According to the OED "consisting of many different and connected parts". One often finds the word used with this more literal meaning. A complex number has a real part and an imaginary part. Complexity Science is the study of systems of many interacting components.

Comment: "You can give opinions for each description 1.–8."  That last sentence makes this question "opinion based": taking a poll of users opinions on your question.  Please do not use this site to take opinion polls about mathematics.